# Command path for exit

Tags: terminal, command-line, path

How would I find the command path for exit?  I have already tried `which exit` but that returns nothing (it just goes to a new line).

I have also played around `cd /usr/bin`, and when in that directory using `ls -R`, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to find it in any directory because it's a builtin command (`man exit`):

> Shell builtin commands are commands that can be executed within the
>   running shell's process.  Note that, in the case of csh(1) builtin commands, the command is executed in a subshell if it occurs as any component of a pipeline except the last.

A list of the Bash builtin commands for macOS can be found at the top of the man page ([`man builtin`](https://ss64.com/bash/)).

Comment: You can check where commands come from (a path, an alias, a function, or a builtin) with the `type` command. e.g. `type exit`

Comment: And `type type` will explain you what is `type` :).

Comment: @danielAzuelos - That's [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)  :-D

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is ksh, zsh, or bash, you can use:

```
type exit
```

or

```
command -V exit
```

To list the builtin commands

bash:

```
compgen -b
```

or

```
enable -a
```

ksh:

```
 builtin
```

zsh:

```
 echo ${(k)builtins}
```

For builtin manuals

bash:

```
 help exit
```

ksh:

```
 exit --man
```

zsh:

```
 man zshbuiltins
```